# How do I get the actual path of the video sent to my app from Gallery via the ContentProvider URI?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app in which I'd like to view a video file that I chose to share from the Gallery to be edited. For that I know I have to use the `intent-filter` tag in the manifest of the Activity.

So here I was, selecting a video from the Gallery app to be 'shared' into this app. When the Activity opens, I used `Uri videoUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);` to retrieve the URI of the video. The URI looks like this:

> `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fdata%2Fdata%2Fcom.google.android.apps.photos%2Fcache%2Fshare-cache%2Fmedia.tmp%3Ffilename%3Dimage.jpg/ORIGINAL/NONE/1804018524`

I can play it just fine in MediaPlayer, but the problem comes when I have to use a library that requires a File [namely, MP4Parser], and that means a file path - this URI doesn't work.

I've parsed the `file%3A%2F%2F%2Fdata%2Fdata%2Fcom.google.android.apps.photos%2Fcache%2Fshare-cache%2Fmedia.tmp%3Ffilename%3Dimage.jpg` part, and it gives me:

> `file:///data/data/com.google.android.apps.photos/cache/share-cache/media.tmp?filename=image.jpg`

The problem with this is that opening it results in an ENOENT. `new File("/data/data/com.google.android.apps.photos/cache/share-cache/media.tmp").exists()` returns false.

I've also queried the URI itself in the cursor via `getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)` and logged all the values inside. All I got was:

> `_id:0
>   _display_name:image.jpg
>   _size:2183131
>   mime_type:video/mpeg
>   _data:null
>   orientation:0
>   datetaken:0
>   latitude:null
>   longitude:null
>   special_type_id:null`

My question: Is there a way to inquire the actual path [either in `file://` form or in `content://media/external/videos/...`] of the video shared by the Gallery app if that URI is what it sends out?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed to do is to open an `InputStream` from said URI via the `ContentResolver`, write it into a `FileOutputStream` directed towards a temporary file (right now I have the temporary file inside my app's `FilesDir`), then use that as the data source instead.